# Understanding parameter (T *const *)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a pointer to a vector of floats that I have, so that I can pass it to a generic function that looks something like this:

```
foo<Type>(Type *const *, size_t)
```

However, as I'm somewhat new to c++, I'm having difficulties understanding how the syntax in the first parameter should be interpreted, in particular the " *const * ". What exactly would I need to put as an argument?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: You need to supply a pointer to a constant pointer to this `Type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there, then it applies to the thing on its right instead.

So, in `Type *const *`, the `const` applies to the 1st `*`.  So this would mean that the parameter is a non-const pointer (the 2nd `*`) to a `const` pointer (the 1st `*`) to a non-const `Type` instance.  Which would be written like this when calling `foo()` with a vector of floats:

```cpp
vector<float> vec;
// populate vec as needed...
float* const ptr = vec.data(); // or: ... = &vec[0];
foo<float>(&ptr, vec.size());
```

However, depending on what `foo()` actually does, you probably don't need that extra level of indirection and can remove one of the pointers:

```cpp
foo<Type>(const Type *, size_t);
```

```cpp
vector<float> vec;
// populate vec as needed...
foo<float>(vec.data()/* or: &vec[0] */, vec.size());
```